# AFImageRequestOperation gets "The request timed out." Error

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios7

I having problem with downloading array of images from server, if i have 100 images on server means i should download all images using "AFImageRequestOperation",  while downloading process some images are downloaded successfully but many images are failed to download because of "TimeOut" error from server,

i using follwing way to downloading images:

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kBaseURLString];
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
[httpClient setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:kUserDefaultKeyUsername]
                                      password:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:kUserDefaultKeyPassword]];

for( int i = 0; i < [self.downloadImageList count]; i++ ) {

    NSString *filename = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[self.downloadImageList objectAtIndex:i]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                                                            path:@"/xxx/yyyyyyyyyy/getImage"
                                                                      parameters:nil
                                                       constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {

                                                           [formData appendPartWithFormData:[filename dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                                                       name:kFormNameFile];

                                                       }];

    AFImageRequestOperation *requestOperation = [[AFImageRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest];
    [requestOperation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {

        [self updateSyncClientUIDelegateProgress:(totalBytesRead/totalBytesExpectedToRead) andLabel:@"Downloading Images"];
    }];

    [requestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {


        if( [[urlRequest URL] isEqual:[[operation request] URL]] ) {

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                UIImage *image = responseObject;
                NSLog(@"Downloading  image %@",image);

                [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:[syncedImagesPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename] atomically:YES];
            });

        }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        if( [[operation response] statusCode] == 404 ) {
            return;
        }
        NSLog(@"failure BLOCK %@",error);
        NSLog(@"failure error code %ld",(long)[error code]);



        if( [error code] != NSURLErrorCannotDecodeContentData ) {

            [self cancelSyncFromFailure];
        }

    }];
```

finally i receives an Error(NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out.") for many image requests,

```
Error Report:   Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo=0x155ef3b0 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://integration.xxx.com/yyy/zzz/getImage, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://xxxx.yyy.com/xxx/yyyyy/getImage, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., NSUnderlyingError=0x1683e130 "The request timed out."}
```

please help me to sort out this issue and how i should approch this issue, Thanks

Comment: hi still im stuck with this issue,can anyone help me to sortout this issue

Answer (score 0):

If you steel have problem try increase timeout value, add this line before creating `requestOperation`

```
[urlRequest setTimeoutInterval:120]; // increase if use slow network/server
```